# Stripe Android, Cannot resolve symbol 'PaymentConfiguration'

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add a Payment Method in Stripe. In the client side (android) I'm adding the dependency `implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:19.1.0'`

The gradle version looks like

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
}
```

And my gradle app file version looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.buscaride.dev"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled=true
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    ...
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:19.1.0'
}
```

So, when I try to `import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;` it says:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PaymentConfiguration'

No clue what I'm missing

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I upgraded Android Studio to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to invalidate Caches in "File Menu -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"?

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt... but didn't work

Comment: OK and is your project sync with gradle file? To be sure you can hit the button "Sync project with Gradle Files" next to the "AVD manager" button

Comment: Yes, didn't work... I also cleaned the project and build it again.

Comment: The example in github is using it... I'm not sure if I didn't understand the documentation https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/v19.1.0/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/ExampleApplication.kt

Comment: I added it normally, could you re-try?

Comment: Sorry @tadev I don't get it... what you added? What I have to retry?